# Is there a way to determine which driver + version is used by a third-party application?

Tags: cassandra

An enterprise is running a [close-sourced] third-party application that connects to their open-source Cassandra cluster. They would like to migrate to a cloud-based Cassandra-as-a-service but need to know if the application can support it.

How can they determine the driver version the application is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra 4.0 added a new feature called [Virtual Tables](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/new/virtualtables.html) ([CASSANDRA-7622](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7622)). These expose server-side configuration settings, metrics and various metadata through CQL instead of JMX.

With the implementation of virtual tables, the client (app/driver) metrics ([`o.a.c.metrics.ClientMetrics.java` class](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/metrics/ClientMetrics.java)) was also refactored ([CASSANDRA-14524](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14524)) and there is a new class that tracks metadata on client connections which include the following ([from `ConnectedClient.java`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/transport/ConnectedClient.java#L129-L143)):

```
    public Map<String, String> asMap()
    {
        return ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
                           .put(ADDRESS, remoteAddress().toString())
                           .put(USER, username().orElse(UNDEFINED))
                           .put(VERSION, String.valueOf(protocolVersion()))
                           .put(DRIVER_NAME, driverName().orElse(UNDEFINED))
                           .put(DRIVER_VERSION, driverVersion().orElse(UNDEFINED))
                           .put(REQUESTS, String.valueOf(requestCount()))
                           .put(KEYSPACE, keyspace().orElse(""))
                           .put(SSL, Boolean.toString(sslEnabled()))
                           .put(CIPHER, sslCipherSuite().orElse(UNDEFINED))
                           .put(PROTOCOL, sslProtocol().orElse(UNDEFINED))
                           .build();
    }
```

specifically, `DRIVER_NAME` and `DRIVER_VERSION`.

For older Cassandra clusters, the alternatives include:

- checking the process table for the driver binary and version;
- checking the application's library subfolders for the driver binary (e.g. JAR file) and associated version.

Cheers!