# How do I get the clients connected to a Cassandra instance?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra

I am trying to get a list of clients connected with their public IPs to my cassandra instance , how can I get those details ?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra 4.0 added a new feature called [Virtual Tables](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/new/virtualtables.html) ([CASSANDRA-7622](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/new/virtualtables.html)). These are tables backed by an API and stored in a virtual keyspace interface.

The idea behind the Virtual Tables feature is that it provides the ability to expose metrics and YAML configuration via CQL.

In your case, the `system_views.clients` table stores information about connected clients (apps). These include:

- the remote IP address of the client
- logged in user (if authentication is enabled)
- native CQL binary protocol version
- driver name & version
- whether SSL is used, etc

For a complete list and more details, see my answer in [Is there a way to determine which driver + version is used by a third-party application?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/327551/).

You can retrieve this information via CQL. Alternatively, you can run the [`nodetool clientstats`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/tools/nodetool/clientstats.html) command.

For earlier versions of Cassandra, you will have to manually interrogate the TCP connections on a node using Linux utilities such as `lsof` or `netstat`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There is an utility called [`nodetool clientstats`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsClientstats.html) which would fetch you the desired result. Example below:

```
nodetool clientstats --all

Address              Cipher Protocol  SSL       Version User      Keyspace  Requests Driver-Name                     Driver-Version     
/10.101.33.110:56948 false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra OpsCenter 26551719 DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
/10.101.34.28:60254  false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra OpsCenter 32504215 DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
/10.101.32.233:46966 false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra           44049    DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
/10.101.32.233:47494 false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra           154225   DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
/10.101.33.110:56954 false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra           44064    DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
/10.101.32.233:47486 false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra           44042    DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
/10.101.33.110:56956 false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra system    44601    DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
/10.101.32.233:46830 false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra           44019    DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
/10.101.32.243:55374 false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra OpsCenter 48268    DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
/10.101.33.110:56946 false  undefined undefined 66      cassandra           44062    DataStax Enterprise Java Driver 1.10.0-dse+20200217
     
Total connected clients: 10
 
User      Connections
cassandra 10
```